# Displaying more data on d3 gantt chart rectangle do not show

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, gantt-chart

Problem : Hi, Thanks in advance. I am working on the gantt chart in d3.I have a created an sandbox d3 gantt chart for the same. My project work fine with 100 or 200 records but don't work for bulk data. I am preparing the data in my **App Component** inside for loop, you can change the value of loop to increase the data and check. Please refer the sanbox url mention below. Can anybody help ?. The problem are
1- If I pass more data like 500 or 6000 records, my gantt chart don't show the rectangle bar
2- There is gap on y-axis top and bottom when I put 300 records, which look very ugly. My y-axis tick not adjusting itself. How can I handle the y-axis ticks if my data increases.

Scenario :
1- Check the gantt chart with 200, 300 records and if you increase more records(like  5000, 1000 or more) rectangle will not show up.

Can anybody please help me on this, I am really struggle to solve it. Let me know if you're not able to access the url, I will share my credentials for sanbox as well. Thank you !!

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-wildflower-qejbx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: A chart with 5K items should have zoom/pan functionality, otherwise it's unmanageable. Here is a simple example of how to do it: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_zoom.html

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will implement zoom. But I am not able to display 500 records also why my y-axis have space on top and bottom on 300 records, Did you try to access my sandbox url

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky, To handle the more data with zoom. Is it like, whenever the my svg load, I am to have to rescale the x and y scales. If yes, At the time of loading, how to know how much I need to rescale, so that it fits in the svg. Thanks in advance

Comment: Get the width and height of your SVG, calculate the width and height of your chart when it expanded to maximum (depends on the number of items and size of an item); Then, your maximum zoom factor is virtual space ( width or height ) / screen space (width or height). Put this value to the scaleExtent of d3.zoom (as upper limit)

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky, As always you ROCKS !!. As per your suggestion I was able to display bulk records in my chart. May god fulfill all of your desire you wish !!

Comment: thank you, my friend :)